# Twitter error with Hello.js

Tags: javascript, twitter, hello.js

I've seen a few people having problems with the oAuth1.0 using hello.js with Twitter, LinkedIn etc. Unfortunately, I am one of them. Trying everything I can to fix it, but I need help.

To explain:

I have my Twitter credentials initialised:

```
hello.init({
    'twitter' : '*******************'
},
{
    redirect_uri:'****************',
    oauth_proxy: 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy'
});
```

(I presume that the 'oauth_proxy' in my case here is correct?)

Apart from that, I have tried calling the function in the button tag like so:

```
onclick="hello.login('twitter');">
```

I have seen people making errors having skipped the 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/#signin' step but I have all my credentials inputted there for the mean time. But, one question:

The 'Reference' section, is that just a nickname kind of thing? And what's the 'Domain' section about?

The error that I'm receiving is a 401 error message.

Another question:

Do I need all of the 'twitter.js' & 'client_id.js', or is including 'hello.js' sufficient?

I appreciate any effort to help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said (after all, he is the one who wrote hello.js), one of the problems could be related to the callback URL. I found out after a while that Twitter (unlike Facebook) does not accept 'localhost', so instead one has to write 127.0.0.1.

That solved all my problem when being stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the reference is a nickname e.g. "dropbox", and the domain field is the domains e.g. "myapp.com". Its advised to fill both these in for your own reference and their misconfiguration wont lead to a 401.

The 401 is likely that your client id / secret is incorrect. Or the `redirect_uri` defined in `hello.init` does not match the Callback URL you assigned to that client id when you registered with a third party service.

The error handler `hello(network).login().then(successHandler, errorHandler)` should give more information. Can you attach that too your question?

"client_id.js" is a demo script which defines the credentials used for my hellojs demos. Do not include it!
However you may like this approach for maintaining your application credentials in a separate file - this approach is left up to you.

All you need to include to get started is dist/hello.all.js this contains hello js and all the third party configurations listed.